# Can I use a bias value outside [0, 1] for SampleBias in HLSL?

Tags: directx, shader, direct3d, hlsl

The doucment [SampleBias](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb944005(v=vs.85).aspx) said that Bias is a floating-point number between 0.0 and 1.0 inclusive. However I have done a little experiment and Bias values outside [0, 1] work fine.

Is Bias value outside [0, 1] guaranteed to work? Or this just depends on hardware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm don't think that the HLSL docs are correct. For DirectX 11, the range for `MipLODBias` in `D3D11_SAMPLE_DESC` is -16 to 16--since the maximum possible number of levels in a 16k x 16k texture would be 16.

```
#define D3D11_MIP_LOD_BIAS_MAX  ( 15.99f )
#define D3D11_MIP_LOD_BIAS_MIN  ( -16.0f )
```